Generate @lombok.Builder.Default annotation in models generated with Openapi-generator
I was trying to migrate my project to spring boot 3 and thus updated lombok to version v1.18.32.
We are trying to generate model classes using open-api-generator plugin and with this new version of lombok, it is expected to use @Builder.default on fields with default value assigned. But unfortunately this annotations is not getting generated at all and I am getting below warning:
*** @Builder will ignore the initializing expression entirely. If you want the initializing expression to serve as default, add @Builder.Default. If it is not supposed to be settable during building, make the field final.***
I want to get this of this warning. Can anyone help me understand on how do we add builder.default annotations while model generation using open-api-generator plugin.
Config in pom.xml :
    <plugin>                
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>execution-test-api-spec</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    <configOptions>
                                      
    <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown =
                                    false) 
    @lombok.NoArgsConstructor 
    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor 
    @lombok.Builder
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
    (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
    @lombok.Builder.Default
    </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
    </configOptions>
    </configuration>
    </execution>`
```


- **Current Output:**

```
public class TestDto {

@JsonProperty("Example")

private List\<Object\> example = new ArrayList\<\>();
}

```
- **Expected Output:**

```
public class TestDto {

@JsonProperty("Example")
**@Builder.Default**
private List\<Object\> example = new ArrayList\<\>();
}
```

